# Can I create process without use standard api function?

Tags: c++, c, process, mfc

Is there any way to create process without using CreateProcess or ShellExecute , WinExec Api Function?

Comment: Explain why you can't use these APIs.

Comment: To create a process, you have to (at some stage) make the system call that will tell the kernel to create a new process. Whatever technique you use, it will eventually lead to the same thing.

Comment: Perhaps instead of asking this question you should explain what you're trying to do and we can then provide a solution.

Comment: Tell us what your problem is

Answer (score 0):

While you can use `system()`, it is considered very bad practice to do so (insecure, inefficient, etc).

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/

Comment: By using this function, Can I create child process from parent with same name?

Comment: @bTagTiger I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "parent with same name".

Comment: Why don't you just tell us what you are trying to *achieve*, instead of what you *think* the solution is, so that we can actually help you?